# Localhost/htdocs Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Al momento de ingresa a localhost/htdocs me muestra la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

teniendo apache y xampp activados, he buscado varias soluciones pero ninguna me permite ingresar.

Lo que busco es ingresas a archivos php que tengo guardados en htdocs, los cuales estoy escribiendo para un curso en php que estoy llevando.

Agradecería me pudieran apoyar con alguna solución.

Answer (score 2):

Hola eso es porque estas intentando ingresar con la URL `http://localhost/htdocs` esa no es la manera correcta de entrar, ya que el servidor corre en la carpeta htdocs es decir que no la tienes que poner en la URL.
Para ingresar solo debes de ingresar a `http://localhost/` y listo.